# Edit Border Around ComboBox

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, combobox, flash-builder

I am trying to remove the border around a ComboBox.  I want to set borderStyle="none" but ComboBox doesn't have a "BorderStyle" option.  I found where it is located using the Adobe Flash Debugger.  The nesting looks like this

```
myComboBox
  -->  styleDeclaration
     -->  styleManager
        -->  stylesRoot
           -->  borderStyle
```

Now this borderStyle is set to "inlet" and I want it to be "none".  However the deepest I have been able to get is to the styleManager.  The styleManager doesn't allow me to access the stylesRoot.  I am wondering how I could get to the stylesRoot in order to change the "borderStyle" property.

The code I used to get to the styleManager looks like the following:

```
var myCSSSD:CSSStyleDeclaration = StyleManager.getStyleDeclaration("ComboBox");
```

*or*

```
var myCSSSD:CSSStyleDeclaration = myComboBox.StyleDeclaration;
```

Any ideas how  can get to this borderStyle property would be great.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Flex controls have setStyle method. [Here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f7e.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  border-style property as following

```
<mx:Style>
  .myComboboxStyle
  {
   border-style: none;
   border-thickness:0;
  }
</mx:Style>
```

and use this style in Combo Box like

```
cmb.setStyle("styleName","myComboboxStyle");
```

where cmb is the name of your Combo Box.

query me if you have nay further question.